# iPhone 4 Retina image not sizing properly with CSS

Tags: iphone, mobile, resolution, retina-display, image-size

I'm trying to save out images for a mobile site.  I'm saving out a hires (width 640px) and a low res (width 320px) for the iPhone 4.  If I view the jpg image in Safari mobile, it shows full width (portrait mode).  If I use it as the background image in the CSS, it takes up about 2/3 of the screen (portrait mode).

I'm using this code to detect the retina screen

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) and (orientation:portrait),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) and (orientation:portrait) {

#header
{
    background:url(images/hires/header.jpg) no-repeat;
    width:640px;
    height:257px;
}

}
```

The only thing that fixes it is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640" />
```

in my HTML header.  But, that would totally nix it for something like an Atrix 2 that has 540px width.  I tried the:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

And then the image was about twice the width of the screen (portrait mode).

I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong or how to cater to every single phone/resolution/screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this seemed to fix it, haven't been able to try it on things other than iPhone 4 and iphonetest.com

(The initial-scale=.5 was the thing that helped)  Not sure what it does

Comment: *note - this fixed it for portrait view, but once I switch to landscape, landscape is double size.  The thing that fixes portrait, breaks landscape.  Argh...